# jest test results after fireEvent.click() (without enzym)

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I can't figure out why the status of the render does not change after the button is clicked for this test framework. It works on the application, but not on the testcase. I have tried reading multiple documentations and using `async/await waitForElement`, `moch renders`, and multiple getBy* combinations... nothing seems to work.

I copied the code on sandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/40pz9nj469

Here is the block of code I am trying to get to work (located in `./src/controls/Controls.spec.js`):

```
it("Testcase: button 'Close Gate' changes to 'Open Gate' upon event click", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Controls />);
  const button = getByTestId("closed");

  expect(button).toHaveTextContent(/Close Gate/i);
  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(button).toHaveTextContent(/Open Gate/i); // <<<fails here>>>
});
```

Failure Message...

[image]

I was told we are not allowed to use enzyme, so mount/shallow is not an option here...

Anyone have any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test does not make sense to begin with.

You are testing if the value has changed after a click but how could the value change if the `closed` value has not changed.

In the context of unit testing and for your component, I would split your test in two parts:

1. Test that the `toggleClosed` function is being called on button clicked.
2. Test that the correct text is displayed based on the `closed` value

So that would give you something like

To test if the function has been called on click

```
    it("Testcase: button 'Close Gate' calls the toggleClosed function upon event click", () => {
      const mockFn = jest.fn();
      const { getByTestId } = render(<Controls toggleClosed={mockFn} />);
      const button = getByTestId("closed");

      fireEvent.click(button);

      expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

to test that the text value is correct, the following 2 tests:

```
it("Testcase: should display 'Open Gate' when closed is true", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Controls closed={true} />);
  const button = getByTestId("closed");

  expect(button).toHaveTextContent(/Open Gate/i);
});

it("Testcase: should display 'Close Gate' when closed is false", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Controls closed={false} />);
  const button = getByTestId("closed");

  expect(button).toHaveTextContent(/Close Gate/i);
});
```

Then in my opinion the second button in your component is fully tested

Comment: Ty for the input on this work around. I guess I was hoping for a way to test the change of text in the element after the button is clicked... but these three combined tests should be acceptable. I also added a `expect(mockFn).not.toHaveBeenCalled();` before the line `fireEvent.click(button);` in the first test to ensure it acknowledges the button was clicked.

Comment: I guess the idea is that you can't unit test what happens outside of your component. (In that case, the closed value changing). That part should be tested as part of the parent component unit tests.